# Reinforcement Learning in context of trajectory planning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Are there RL methods that allow for planning under variable objectives? Suppose I have a robot and want to find a policy $\pi$ that takes in the robot's current state $s_t$ and a goal state $s_{\text{goal}}$, and computes the control sequence $u$ to realize the goal state.

$u \sim \pi(\cdot|s_t, s_\text{goal})$

I'm aware of methods like iLQG and AICO, which are fast enough to work in real-time but they require robust dynamics models.

Would policy gradients work here, or is the potential sample space too large? It seems like changing the goal specifies an entirely new MDP.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot afford to learn $k$ objective-dependent policies for $k$ different objectives, or you **really** want something to generalize across goal inputs, then you could try a policy gradient method that takes the goal as input. You are correct that the MDP is different, because you're implicitly changing the reward structure when $s_\text{goal}$ is a parameter.

Here's an example approach of exactly this (in a synthetic environment):

[Target-driven Visual Navigation in Indoor Scenes
using Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05143.pdf)

There is a body of work on learning to generalize across MDPs; your problem is one instances of this.